# Calculating wavelength in photoelectric effect

Tags: homework-and-exercises, photoelectric-effect

How do I know what wavelength should radiate on a material with $W =  2.46 eV$ so that electrons are emitted with a maximum velocity of $1.0$x$10^{-6}$?

Comment: You should read the rules about posing homework problems. You need to demonstrate some attempt to solving the problem. Specifically, what concepts are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I didn't know that. I did do some progress but the result is quite strange. I first calculated de kinectic energy that would be associated with that velocity by using 511000 as the mass (im not sure here). With that kinectic energy I then calculated the photon energy required (W + Ec). With that calculation I finally used it in E = h c/lambda to retrieve the wavelength lambda

Comment: First of all, 511,000 eV is the rest mass of an electron in units of energy. This doesn't work if you're plugging in your mass in units of eV into KE = (1/2)mv^2.
Just stick to SI units.

What is (W+Ec)?

Comment: That would equal the photon energy required to emit an electron that has a binding energy of W which I plug in to E = h * (c/lamda) to retrieve the wavelength

Comment: The KE of an ejected electron is equal to the excess energy of the radiation from however much it takes to ionize it(the work function). So the energy of the radiation must be the sum of the KE of the electron and the work function. I don't know why you're using Ec to signify KE.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I've been studying for so long I forgot to actually translate it. We use Ec for KE in Portugal. Terribly sorry about that.

Comment: So if I plug the mass in kg (SI) for the KE calculation, it'll be correct? It does provide me with a more real wavelength result, however I was told that I should use the rest mass of an electron when calculating KE for photoelectric effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Einstein's photoelectric effect

$hv - hv_0 = 1/2mv^2 $  where $hv_0 $= work function and $hv$ is the energy of the incident photon.

$hv = 1/2mv^2 + hv_0 $

By **c= f * z**

where ***f = frequency*** and ***z = wavelength***

$hc/z = 1/2mv^2 + hv_0$

$z/hc = 1 / (1/2mv^2 + hv_0)$

$z = hc / (1/2mv^2 + hv_0)$